# The maximium number of tables for sqlite3

Tags: sql, linux, sqlite

The the limits or suggestion about *maximum number of tables* with **sqlite3**.  On 64bits Linux OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sqlite limits](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) does not specify a maximum number of tables.
And since sqlite was intended to have as few limits as possible I would conclude that there is no limit.

Comment: `To have as few limits as possible` is an design intention of *sqlite*. As recent versions, sqlite3, it shows they are going to make limits clearer than 'less limits'.  But I think this should not concern the number of tables in normal usage.  Just for cases.